# Returning int from one method to use in another method

Tags: c#, methods, return

Thanks for all the quick responses. They all really helped.

Hi all I'm new to C# and strongly typed languages.

I'm trying to return the int amount from my WithdrawAmount method so that I can then use it as a parameter in my DispenseCash cash method. I am getting the error "The name 'amount' does not exist in the current context".

What am I doing wrong and if it's not too much trouble could I be directed to online resources to learn more on the problem. Thanks :).

```
int whichAccount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
do
    {
         WithdrawAmount(whichAccount);

         DispenseCash(amount, whichAccount, invalidAmount);
    } while (invalidAmount == true);

// end of little example segment of Main  



static int WithdrawAmount(int whichAccount)
    {
        Console.Write("\nPlease enter how much you would like to withdraw: $");
        int amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return amount; 
    }//end WithdrawAmount



private static bool DispenseCash(int amount, int whichAccount, bool invalidAmount)
        {
            int numOf20s;
            int numOf50s;

            if (amount % 20 == 0)
            {
                numOf20s = amount / 20;
                Console.WriteLine("Number of 20's = {0}", numOf20s);
                accountBalances[whichAccount] = (accountBalances[whichAccount]) - amount;
                return invalidAmount == false;


            }
            else if (amount % 50 == 0)
            {
                numOf50s = amount / 50;
                Console.WriteLine("Number of 50's = {0}", numOf50s);
                return invalidAmount == false;
            }


            else if ((amount - 50) % 20 == 0)
            {
                numOf50s = 1;
                numOf20s = (amount - 50) / 20;
                Console.WriteLine("Number of 20's = {0}", numOf20s);
                Console.WriteLine("Number of 50's = {0}", numOf50s);
                return invalidAmount == false;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry");
                return invalidAmount == true;
            }

        }//end DispenseCash
```

Comment: What is the use of this line int whichAccount = 
        int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: That is so that users can select which bank account they wish to withdraw from.

Comment: ok.. you are passing the whichAccount  to WithdrawAmount() method. But  you are not using that whichAccount  in that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you haven't declared a variable called `amount`.

I believe you wanted to declare a variable `amount` and assign the return value of the call to `WithdrawAmount` to it:

```
int amount = WithdrawAmount(whichAccount);
```

Then use it to call `DispenseCash`:

```
DispenseCash(amount, whichAccount, invalidAmount);
```

---

Note you can also do this inline:

```
DispenseCash(WithdrawAmount(whichAccount), whichAccount, invalidAmount);
```

---

Furthermore, looking at your code, you will most likely be in an infinite loop since nothing changes the value of `invalidAmount`. I believe instead of passing it as a parameter in `DispenseCash` and comparing the existing value, you really wanted to generate the value from `DispenseCash` and return it. Therefore having

```
invalidAmount = !DispenseCash(WithdrawAmount(whichAccount), whichAccount);
```

Note I have inverted the logic since it makes more sense to return `true` from a successful dispensement of cash, rather than to return whether it was invalid or not.

Comment: Thanks, where do you think I should assign it?

Comment: @user2281248 Where you are calling it (in main?). Perhaps you should do a google search about "variable scope". You might be thinking you already have a variable called "amount" but that is only inside the WithdrawAmount method.

Answer (score 0):

your withdraw amount method is fine.

Though this line would be giving you error

```
DispenseCash(amount, whichAccount, invalidAmount);
```

because you haven't declared `amount` anywhere in your code.

as you want to return amount from `withdrawamount` method and then call dispense cash method. So, what you basically need is this.

```
int amount =WithdrawAmount(whichAccount);
DispenseCash(amount, whichAccount, invalidAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

since your `WithdrawAmount(whichAccount)` returns **int** there is no need to assign a new variable and set value to it, instead you can try this

```
 DispenseCash(WithdrawAmount(whichAccount), whichAccount, invalidAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually:

```
int whichAccount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
do
    {
         int amount = WithdrawAmount(whichAccount);

         DispenseCash(amount, whichAccount, invalidAmount);
    } while (invalidAmount == true);
```

See, when you have a return value, you have to store it somewhere if you wish for it to be recognized by other functions (and just by the rest of the program, really). As for good resources, can't go wrong with following [these](http://readwrite.com/2011/05/28/free-e-books-on-c#awesm=~ofYpKGmtf5bvFS).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
do
{
    int amount = WithdrawAmount(whichAccount);

     DispenseCash(amount, whichAccount, invalidAmount);
} while (invalidAmount == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the return value of the call to WithdrawAmount to a variable:

```
int whichAccount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
do
{
     int amount=WithdrawAmount(whichAccount);

     DispenseCash(amount, whichAccount, invalidAmount);
} while (invalidAmount == true);
```